# Get Sum of rows of SQL query that satisfies multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table and I am trying to get the sum of Col A to 2 decimal places of all rows (there is an id column ID) that satisfies the following:

1) There is another row with a matching Col B

2) It has an unique pair of the values in Col C and Col D

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and tag the database correctly.

Comment: Please tag properly.  MySQL or Oracle?????  Can't be both.

Comment: What have you tried so far????  Before asking question, learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(SUM(ColA), 2) AS ColA_Sum

FROM datatable t

WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM datatable t2
    WHERE t2.ID <> t.ID -- Another row must have different id
    AND t2.ColB = t.ColB -- Matching Column B

)

AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM datatable t3
    WHERE t3.ColC = t.ColC -- Same Column C
    AND t3.ColD = t.ColD -- Same Column D
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 -- Only 1 row with such values
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be as simple as:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(t.cola), 2) AS cola_sum
FROM t
WHERE cola = colb
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM t t2
 WHERE t2.colc = t.colc
 AND t2.cold = t.cold
 GROUP BY colc, cold
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Check out the test here: http://rextester.com/BSVW57900